# wants to add import/export functionality in my C# appliction

Tags: c#, import, export

I want to add import/export functionality in my C# app...

export my sql server data to file(CSV,XLS,XML)
  import the data to sql server from exported file(CSV,XML,XLS)

Kindly suggest in which format(CSV,XML or XSL) I should do import/export as I am fine with any of it.. It just depends how easily I am doing it..

Also provide me the links or directions such that I can get detail of this and start coding on this..

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stand for `CSV` file format if your application should trasmit/operate on large amount of data. `CSV` has low memory footprint, as it's just `comma-separated` text. The difficulty with that type of format comes in case of international applications, when you have (say) different decimal seprators on different machines and need to save/restore data form another  machine. In this case, you need

- or store in some way culture information in the file
- or define single uniform format for **all** clients.

For work with `CSV` you can use [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)

For small chunks of data, or for trabsmitting it via network or communicating it between different processes you can relay on `XML` format, which has  a huge built-in support in `.NET Framework` for persistancy, serialization and navigation.

Nothing to say about `XLS`, cause I try always to avoid them, cause they are proprietary format and not common format for most of IT world. You need to have and `Excel` installed or you can use some 3rd part libraries, like [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out FileHelpers.

http://www.filehelpers.net/

it support wizards and all the formats you can think of.